# Disable AutoNumber in MS Access 2000 Database

Tags: c#, ms-access

Currently in one of our legacy system's database has one of its columns set to AutoNumber. I am investigating if there is a work around to circumvent this to allow the program to enter its own values into this column.

Perhaps some way to programatically disable the AutoNumber-ing process then re-enabling it again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is the problem? You can insert your own numbers into an autonumber field as long as they are unique, but if you want your own numbers, you should not be using an autonumber.

Comment: I get this message : 

{"The changes you requested to the table were not successful because they would create duplicate values in the index, primary key, or relationship.  Change the data in the field or fields that contain duplicate data, remove the index, or redefine the index to permit duplicate entries and try again."}

Comment: I understand what you are saying, as I stated in my question I was wondering is there a work around for this issue. If so please let me know. Believe me, if it were up to me I would also not opt for this as well.

Comment: 1. You do not need to insert a number at all : `UPDATE MyTable (MyText) VALUES ('Text')` or 2. `UPDATE MyTable (Id, MyText) VALUES (-99, 'Text')` ie a number that does not exist in the table. Option 2 is likely to play havoc with subsequent numbers.

Comment: @remou I see where you are going towards. I guess the issue I am getting is because the test database I am using has the values entered before and has its rows removed. Perhaps the value is stored in the autonumber internal data store to prevent the value being entered again. This would indeed cause an issue even with the ADOX method being put in place.

Comment: @Benjamin Wong Compact and repair the database. It will reset the numbers and is a good idea anyway.

Comment: @remou -> Yeap, now I am able to test this. My app is now complete. I sure hope that this won't come and bite me later =) Thanks again for your effort in helping me out. Will return the favor when the opportunity comes up.

Comment: @Benjamin Wong I have been using autonumbers for quite some time, and as long as all you ask of them is that they be unique, they will generally behave.

Comment: @Benjamin Wong: Implied in Remou's comments, but not explicitly stated, is that Access doesn't *really* remove the deleted rows until the Compact operation, so your "new" numbers are *not* unique, even though they look like they are.

Comment: If the deleted numbers were reused, you could end up with a truly horrible mess from a relational point of view, so the table must be empty before numbers are reset, unless you tamper, which is a good reason for not tampering.

Comment: @RolandTumble: there are actually two issues that are taken care of with a compact. One is the discarding of unused data pages (i.e., the ones where the deleted records used to live), but the other is the Autonumber seed value, which is not reset until a compact (and not always in all cases -- it's complicated).

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: That's what I was trying to get across, but you said it better. It _can't_ reset the seed until it discards those pages, since it still has them hanging around....

Comment: No, I don't think that's true. When the data pages are discarded, they are really discarded -- no longer part of the data table structure. It's the seed value that has to be reset, and that's independent of the data pages. In short, I don't think there's any dependency between the two at all -- they just happened to be done in a single operation.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't modify the type of the column of the database through a C# program. You have to change the Column type of the Column in `Design View` of the Table column in the `MS-Access`.

Update: You can change the type of Column if it is an AutoNumber but after adding the data, you wont get back to AutoNumber.

Comment: That will not work even in Access if data has already been added to the autonumber field.

Comment: BTW I cannot see why you should not use the DAO libraries to change data types.

Comment: @Renmou What do you mean by DAO libraries? Are you referring to the .NET ADO libraries?

Comment: Sigh, that is what I feared. So the auto-number increments would be broken even if I managed to do it?

Comment: Why do you care about the values of an Autonumber field? You don't seem to understand the purpose of it.

Comment: @david-w-fenton : I know what it does, it was a request for me to explore it and I did. Thats the short and abridged version of why I am doing this bit of fact finding.

Answer (score 0):

Use Alter Statements
and Adox for changing the fieldtype from autonumber to integer

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Pardon my ignorance as I am more used to working with SharePoint and SQL Server and my issue is also quite novel for me as well. Perhaps you can provide a sample or point me to some literature I can go thru?

Comment: Sure let me surf the correct resource for you. The problem you stated definately has a solution. I just lost my bookmarks. Give me 10 minutes at max.

Comment: check this link http://allenbrowne.com/func-adox.html. This is in VB. Can you convert the code in C#??

Comment: For alter statement use this :-ALTER TABLE tablename ALTER COLUMN columnname Number(10);

Comment: @ankush-roy : I will give it a shot. Thanks =)

Update : Wow, looks like VB6. Been awhile since I have seen this.

Comment: Check this also http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/Changing-Field-Type-ADOX-t608774.html

Comment: Looks like I have a workings of something I can use now. One question, which ADOX method should I use to set the AutoNumber back to the last number I inserted?

Comment: This is a really bad idea. It will cause problems with your database.

Comment: @ankush-roy : Thanks for the pointers, managed to get an easier way out. This was an interesting intellectual exercise though. Thanks again for your effort in helping me out. Will return the favor when the opportunity comes up.

Comment: @Remou : Exactly what kind of problems? Please Elaborate Sir.

Comment: I just answered what the question demanded. ADOX is the only way I knew which will Disable AutoNumber field and change it into number field n access. I agree due to that the user will have to generate the next number himself/herself for the number column but thats what Benjamin Wong asked for

Comment: A better approach would have been :- 1) update all entries in autonumber field in a sorted manner 2) reset the autonumber to the Table.Rows.Length. through ADOX itself